# Cannot get windows 8 to boot after ubuntu 12.10 install (different hdds)

Tags: 12.10, boot, grub2, dual-boot, windows-8

I just took the plunge into Linux, with Ubuntu 12.10. Not knowing if I would like Ubuntu enough for it to become my main OS, I installed it alongside of my existing OS, windows 8. When installing Ubuntu, I installed it to a completely separate and empty hard drive.I can boot into Ubuntu perfectly fine, and Grub shows windows 8 (loader) as an option, however when I do try to boot into windows, I receive this:

[image]

Both hard drives are in and working, and I have tried running the recommended settings from boot repair. When my hard drive that has Ubuntu installed on it is removed from the system, I can get windows to boot. From Ubuntu I can look at my other hard drive, and I see that there is a folder called boot in the home directory, could this possibly be what is causing my problems? If yes, can I just delete it, or is there a special way to remove it? And if not, what should I try to remedy this problem? Thanks a ton guys!

Contents of grub.cfg

```
    #
    # DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
    #
    # It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
    # from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
    #

    ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
    if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
      set have_grubenv=true
      load_env
    fi
    set default="0"

    if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
      menuentry_id_option="--id"
    else
      menuentry_id_option=""
    fi

    export menuentry_id_option

    if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
    set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
      save_env saved_entry
      set prev_saved_entry=
      save_env prev_saved_entry
      set boot_once=true
    fi

    function savedefault {
      if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
        saved_entry="${chosen}"
        save_env saved_entry
      fi
    }

    function recordfail {
      set recordfail=1
      if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env     recordfail; fi; fi
    }

    function load_video {
      if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
        insmod all_video
      else
        insmod efi_gop
        insmod efi_uga
        insmod ieee1275_fb
        insmod vbe
        insmod vga
        insmod video_bochs
        insmod video_cirrus
      fi
    }

    if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
       font=unicode
    else
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-    efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  795aa714-904a-41e1-b953-4b818caec860
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 795aa714-904a-41e1-b953-4b818caec860
    fi
        font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
    fi

    if loadfont $font ; then
      set gfxmode=auto
      load_video
      insmod gfxterm
      set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
      set lang=en_US
      insmod gettext
    fi
    terminal_output gfxterm
    if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ]; then
      set timeout=10
    else
      set timeout=10
    fi
    ### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

    ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
    set menu_color_normal=white/black
    set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
    if background_color 44,0,30; then
      clear
    fi
    ### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

    ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
    function gfxmode {
            set gfxpayload="${1}"
        if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
                set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
        else
            set vt_handoff=
        fi
    }
    if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
    if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
        if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
        if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
            set linux_gfx_mode=keep
        else
            set linux_gfx_mode=text
        fi
        else
          set linux_gfx_mode=text
        fi
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
    export linux_gfx_mode
    if [ "${linux_gfx_mode}" != "text" ]; then load_video; fi
    menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os     $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-795aa714-904a-41e1-b953-4b818caec860' {
    recordfail
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-    efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  795aa714-904a-41e1-b953-4b818caec860
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 795aa714-904a-41e1-b953-4b818caec860
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-25-generic root=UUID=795aa714-904a-41e1-b953-4b818caec860 ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-25-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-795aa714-904a-41e1-b953-4b818caec860' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-25-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.5.0-25-generic-advanced-795aa714-904a-41e1-b953-4b818caec860' {
    recordfail
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  795aa714-904a-41e1-b953-4b818caec860
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 795aa714-904a-41e1-b953-4b818caec860
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.5.0-25-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-25-generic root=UUID=795aa714-904a-41e1-b953-4b818caec860 ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-25-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-25-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.5.0-25-generic-recovery-795aa714-904a-41e1-b953-4b818caec860' {
    recordfail
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  795aa714-904a-41e1-b953-4b818caec860
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 795aa714-904a-41e1-b953-4b818caec860
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.5.0-25-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-25-generic root=UUID=795aa714-904a-41e1-b953-4b818caec860 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-25-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-17-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.5.0-17-generic-advanced-795aa714-904a-41e1-b953-4b818caec860' {
    recordfail
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  795aa714-904a-41e1-b953-4b818caec860
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 795aa714-904a-41e1-b953-4b818caec860
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.5.0-17-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic root=UUID=795aa714-904a-41e1-b953-4b818caec860 ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-17-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.5.0-17-generic-recovery-795aa714-904a-41e1-b953-4b818caec860' {
    recordfail
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  795aa714-904a-41e1-b953-4b818caec860
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 795aa714-904a-41e1-b953-4b818caec860
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.5.0-17-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic root=UUID=795aa714-904a-41e1-b953-4b818caec860 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  795aa714-904a-41e1-b953-4b818caec860
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 795aa714-904a-41e1-b953-4b818caec860
    fi
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin
}
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  795aa714-904a-41e1-b953-4b818caec860
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 795aa714-904a-41e1-b953-4b818caec860
    fi
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Dell Utility Partition (on /dev/sdb1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-07D7-090A' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod fat
    set root='hd1,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos1  07D7-090A
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 07D7-090A
    fi
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
menuentry 'Windows 8 (loader) (on /dev/sdb3)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-7CBC4093BC404A3A' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd1,msdos3'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos3 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos3 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos3  7CBC4093BC404A3A
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 7CBC4093BC404A3A
    fi
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

This is the output of mount and `sudo parted /dev/sda print`:

```
Model: ATA Hitachi HDS72168 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 80.0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  76.8GB  76.8GB  primary   ext4            boot
 2      76.8GB  80.0GB  3150MB  extended
 5      76.8GB  80.0GB  3150MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
```

Comment: add the contents of `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. then, leave the contents of the harddrive showing in a window, and from a terminal, tell us the output of `mount` and `sudo parted /dev/sda print` (and lesson for life: learn what a command does when someone tells you to run it as sudo :)

Comment: You don't need to add four spaces at the end of every line, just select the code and press the [code button](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yECDJ.png).  A lot easier for long code blocks :)

Answer (score 0):

Just run the windows boot-repair and Windows will be the sole OS loading...   Then, when you want to boot Ubuntu, go to the BIOS boot options and boot from your second drive.

(I know the user hasn't been on-line for a while, but it might help others with the same problem)